# sentry upgrade from 9.1.2 to 20.10.1 is not working

Tags: docker, sentry

sentry upgrade from 9.1.2 to 20.10.1 is not working

I am running sentry 9.1.2 in docker container, so I want to upgrade to sentry 20.10.1 version and i am using the getsentry/sentry:20.10.1 docker image

steps i followed

1. i took the postgres database backup and stored in my local folder
2. Now I create a docker container running sentry 20.10.1 version and I restored the database

The issue is the data and the projects i have in sentry 9.1.2 version is not getting updated in the sentry 20.10.1 version , so can i get help on what might be the issue